# JQuery not working with JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown list. For some reason, jQuery won't work with JSON in my example. This is the first time I am using JSON and I'm getting myself used to it. I have also googled it, but no luck.
Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
.
.
.

<select id="json-one">
    <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
    <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
    <!--option value="snacks">Snacks</option-->
</select>
<br />
<select id="json-two">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
  "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#text-one").change(function() {
      $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
    });
    $("#json-one").change(function() {
      var $dropdown = $(this);
      $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];
        switch(key) {
          case 'lw':
            vals = data.lw.split(",");
            break;
          case 'g1v1':
            vals = data.g1v1.split(",");
            break;
          case 's2v1':
            vals = data.s2v1.split(",");
            break;
          case 'base':
            vals = ['Please choose from above'];
        }
        var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
        $jsontwo.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
          $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

PS
JQuery is in the head tags.

Comment: Please describe the actual problem. *"jQuery won't work with JSON"* is not an adequate description

Comment: I think you forgot to add your jquery code into page..

Comment: @phil, I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown list.

Comment: First thing I can see is that none of your `switch` cases match your `json-one` options (except for `base`, which does nothing).

Comment: @user1695813 I can see what you're *trying* to do. What you haven't done is describe the *problem* you're having.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console. I have corrected the cases on switch and tried Phil's answer but still not json is not working..

Comment: The second drop down wont populate when an item in the first drop down is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a `switch` statement like that. How about the following

```
var vals = data[key] ? data[key].split(',') : ['Please choose from above'];
```

Also, you should really be using an array in your JSON for each sub-option, eg

```
{
    "beverages": ["Coffee","Coke"],
    "snacks": ["Chips","Cookies"]
}
```

This way, you wouldn't have to use `split` above.

Comment: I tried saving my file on html format, it's working perfectly. How do I make it work on asp file??

Comment: @user1695813 What file? I see no .NET code in your question so don't see how that's relevant at all.